# Use the np.concatenate to join the column

Tags: python, numpy

```
mean_month=np.mean(Sktm_temp_1999_2011[1:13,:],axis=1)
max_month=np.max(Sktm_temp_1999_2011[1:13,:],axis=1)
min_month=np.min(Sktm_temp_1999_2011[1:13,:],axis=1)
np.savetxt('temp_mean_max_min.txt',np.concatenate((mean_month,max_month,min_month),axis=1),fmt='%1.1f')
```

Comment: AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you share what you're trying to do and what you've tried? Also, if you have additional information to add (such as an error message), please put that in the question rather than the comments.

Comment: `np.mean` reduces a 2d array to 1d.  You can't concatenate a list of arrays on a nonexistent axis.  When you get errors like this, check the shape of the relevant arrays.   And look into using `keepdims=True` in the `np.mean` statements.  But even this I encourage you to verify the shapes.

Comment: There's also a `column_stack`.  But I encourage people to read the code of these `stack` functions first, to better understand how `concatenate` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your data (in array Sktm_temp_1999_2011), it's not clear what you're trying to do, or where the error occurs. It looks like some kind of monthly temperature data for years 1999-2011. :-) (12 months, 13 years)
First, check your range for np.mean, np.max and np.min. Do you really want 1:13, or did you intend 0:13 to get statistics for each month over 13 years?
Also, axis=1 uses the second index. Is this the index to months in your data?
To show how this *could work* , I created some data for Sktm_temp_1999_2011, size [13,12]. Rows are years, columns are months. I calculated the statistics (w/ axis=0 to get monthly data in each column). The 3 arrays are then copied to a new array. You could also concatenate, but not sure why you would want mean,max,min in a 1d array. From here you can format as desired for printing.

```
Sktm_temp_1999_2011 = np.arange(156).reshape(13,12)
mean_month=np.mean(Sktm_temp_1999_2011[0:13,:],axis=0)
max_month=np.max(Sktm_temp_1999_2011[0:13,:],axis=0)
min_month=np.min(Sktm_temp_1999_2011[0:13,:],axis=0)
stat_data=np.zeros([3,12])
stat_data[0,:]=mean_month
stat_data[1,:]=max_month
stat_data[2,:]=min_month
print (stat_data)
```

Output:

```
[[  72.   73.   74.   75.   76.   77.   78.   79.   80.   81.   82.   83.]
 [ 144.  145.  146.  147.  148.  149.  150.  151.  152.  153.  154.  155.]
 [  0.    1.    2.    3.    4.    5.    6.    7.    8.    9.   10.   11.]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much@user10462884